# Differentials question evaluating.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $xs^2 + yt^2 = 1$ and $sx^2 + y^2t = xy - 4$, find $\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}$, $\frac{∂x}{∂t}$, $\frac{∂y}{∂s}$, $\frac{∂y}{∂t}$, at
$(x, y, s, t) = (1,−3, 2,−1)$. Hint: To simplify the work, substitute the numerical values just after you have taken differentials.

What is the method behind this?

I started to take total differentials and and substitute one equation in the other (after shoving in numerical values), is that the right way to go? I end up with 2 equations and need to get 4 unknowns?

Comment: Great! you are giving a hint atleast! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Why am I getting downvotes?

Comment: The downvotes is due to lack of any attempt to proceed with an obvious homework/class type assignment. Can you outline if it is the partial differentiation that you have a problem with? Since I can safely assume you know the differentiation process?

Answer (score 1):

I will go through one of your problems and then hopefully the rest will become easier to determine.

We have 
$$
xs^2+yt^2=1\\
sx^2+y^2t=xy−4
$$
do we want to compute $\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}$ we have
$$
s^2\frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + 2sx + t^2\frac{\partial y}{\partial s} = 0\\
x^2 + 2sx\frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + 2yt\frac{\partial y}{\partial s} = y\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+x\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}
$$
we then collect terms
$$
s^2\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+ t^2\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}  = - 2sx \\
\left(2sx-y\right)\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}  + (2yt-x)\frac{\partial y}{\partial s} =-x^2
$$
multiple the first by $(2yt-x)$ and the second by $t^2$ we obtain
$$
s^2(2yt-x)\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+ t^2(2yt-x)\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}  = - 2sx(2yt-x)\\
t^2\left(2sx-y\right)\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}  + t^2(2yt-x)\frac{\partial y}{\partial s} =-t^2x^2
$$
subtract thw two we have
$$
\left[s^2(2yt-x)-t^2\left(2sx-y\right)\right]\frac{\partial x}{\partial s} = - 2sx(2yt-x)+t^2x^2
$$
re-arrange and take it from there. You notice you get $\partial_s y$ for free.

Alternatively you can create an equation $x = f(s,t)$

we have 
$$
y =\frac{1-xs^2}{t^2}
$$
insert into the remaining equation
$$
sx^2+\left(\frac{1-xs^2}{t^2}\right)^2t = \left(\frac{1-xs^2}{t^2}\right)x - 4
$$
expand and then you can compute the implicit derivative with respect to $s$ or $t$.

Comment: Thanks, but when you took differential at the top, you assumed t to be constant with respect to s, how can you do this?

Comment: if they are as independent as x,y shoulndt they have a non zero relation since dx/dy =/= 0, or am I missing something?, I will have a look at similar pronlems

Comment: you are right about the relationship between $x$ and $y$ (or at least more right that I was initially) but looking at your equations it seems that $s,t$ are independent. To break this confusion does your problem have any information regarding what is independent?